# Нужно сделать СЦЕНУ для ЗАГРУЗКИ СЦЕН в unity

Tags: unity3d

Короче говоря, нужно сделать так : есть сцена Menu, на ней ест кнопка, которая запускает функцию, которая в свою очередь грузит "легкую" сцену LoadingScreen с индикатором (Текстовый объект), который будет отображать прогресс загрузки более сложной сцены (Game). Вопрос в том как передать название сцены со сцены Menu на LoadingScreen, которая начнет грузить эту самую сцену.

Comment: сохраняйте его через `PlayerPrefs`

Comment: А вообще есть вариант попроще. Не обязательно грузить новую сцену для загрузки большой сцены. Просто делайте панель загрузки поверх всех окон

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Ответ

Сохраняйте имя сцены вот так -

```cs
PlayerPrefs.SetString("SaveKey", sceneName);
```

Загружайте так -

```cs
SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetString("SaveKey"));
```

---

## Решение получше

Я бы не посоветовал вам создать для загрузки отдельную сцену. Вместо этого используйте отдельный поток.

### Код

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Loading : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int sceneId;
    public Image progress;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        StartCoroutine(loadLevel());
    }

    IEnumerator loadLevel()
    {
        AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneId);
        progress.fillAmount = operation.progress;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

### Окно Loading

#### В Иерархии

[image]

#### В инспекторе

[image]

## Работоспособность

[image]

## Дополнительно

Всё что вам надо это вставить все сцены в Scenes In Build
[image]

И во время загрузки в скрипте показать какую сцену собирайтесь загрузить. В данном случае это сцена с индексом 1.

[image]

Comment: У меня просто сцена слишком быстро загрузился поэтому там всего 1 кадр показывающий [панель загрузки](http://prntscr.com/rmp4rk)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Ваш вариант конечно хорош. Но мне требовался немного другой вариант решения. Но все равно спасибо )